# Why can't I move iOS storyboard elements around?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to work with storyboards in iOS, and it's driving me nuts because I can't drag storyboard elements around in the UI to clean up the visual structure of the relationships. Should I be able to move them around? If so, what might I be doing wrong?

I should note I am accessing the Mac environment via RealVNC on Windows, which might have something to do with it, and I have little choice in the matter, unfortunately. But I have no problems moving UI elements around within a view. It's just the top-level storyboard views that I can't rearrange.

**EDIT:** I've dropped the storyboard tag, since this seems to affect all top-level views and windows in my Xcode editor, not just those belonging to storyboards.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I ran into this problem using a Synergy client on a mac. I assume it has something to do with the mouse lag and how the storyboard registers click and drag. My solution for now is to use a mouse connected directly to the mac, but it would be nice if the Apple would fix this issue in future xcode releases.

Comment: It's funny you should mention that. I switched to using Synergy as well, and ended up doing exactly the same thing: attaching a mouse to manipulate top-level views. I noticed that right-click dragging also doesn't work through Synergy.

Comment: +1 for this, was wondering why the storyboard seemed so crippled!

Comment: Great catch. Last thing I would have thought of.

Comment: Yes, excellent catch.  I am having this problem using screen sharing.  Was driving me nuts.  Still is, but at least I know what is happening now.

Comment: seems to be happening to me using logmein.com

Comment: Same problem using ShareMouse.

Comment: This issue still exists using VNC Viewer and screen sharing... 5 years later -.-

Answer (score 6):

I was facing this, I have a magic trackpad, and as it turns out if you point your mouse on the battery symbol in the storyboard and try to move them, you can do it very easily! :) (not sure if this is a known thing, just adding it here, if somebody has the same question since google's first hit is this one)

[image]

EDIT: Well you can just drag it around using the controller bar below the storyboard so this answer is a little late, but now there are two ways. :)

Comment: OP clearly mentioned he is using VNC.  This does not work with RealVNC

Comment: What controller bar are you referring to?

I can't seem to locate it (does it still exist in XCode7?).
If this is still there, can you please post a picture. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After trying almost every remote screen implementation I could get my hands on, I've come to the same conclusion.

This also affects control-drag for connections. The workaround on ctrl-drag is to right click on an element and drag from the pop-up menu.

For dragging top-level elements, I have a spare mouse connected to the mac like you. But this fix isn't robust because if the mac (running VNC) doesn't have a monitor attached, the remote cursor does not seem to report itself to VNC clients correctly. Is this consistent with your findings, or does your mac have a monitor connected? Reboot with a monitor and I suspect your mac-mouse will not behave correctly through VNC. The fix here is to connect a monitor to the mac briefly, and then remote cursor reports itself correctly from that point onwards (until the next reboot).

Comment: I never tried using a separate mouse with VNC. I eventually switched to a real screen with Synergy.

Answer (score 1):

I just bumped into the same issue, I was using Synergy v. 1.3.7 on Mac (Client) and Synergy v. 1.4.4 on Linux (Server).

I upgraded to Synergy 1.4.10 on both Mac and Linux and now **everything works for me as expected.**

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, however, this actually makes things worse, since I can no longer Ctrl+Click on UI objects to bring up their context view. Right-Click never worked for this purpose, but now nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I am using teamviewer from my windows desktop to connect to my macbook and have the same problem.
I couldn't solve it on my desktop anyways, you have to make these changes in mac.

Comment: Did you find a solution eventually?

I am unable to use a mouse connected to my mac as the mac isn't reachable at this time.

Comment: No, I just gave up using storyboard :D Now doing all my UI on code

Answer (score 1):

As a partial solution when using Google remote desktop:

1. Drag a new item from the Object library. This is working normally until you drop the item. Afterwards you can't drag the item again.
2. Open the outline view. See picture at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Art/2_outlineview_toggle_2x.png

Than drag the item from there. You can drag it and when dropped, the original item will be moved to the correct place. The problem with that is no help lines are presented in order to align the item and no accurate position can be done.

3. Use the Size inspector. See pic at https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2015/11/46_vc_size-e1448290482977-421x320.png

From there you can set the correct size and position of the item.

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Mac in a VMWare Virtual Machine through VNC from Windows, same problem.  However, logging in to VSphere directly, and opening a console on the VM **does** let you move elements **and** control-drag.

This requires access to VSphere, though, which your System Administrator may be reluctant to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I was using ShareMouse 3.0.35 for sharing mouse and keyboard between a PC and a MAC and when I turn it off, I can drag things around on the storyboard.  Posting this to assist others.  Of course, now I have to push my manual KVM which is a drag (pun intended)

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing this on WMware player 14 and macOS 10.13 with Xcode 9.  The only workaround I've found is under the pane with the vertical ruler icon, in the section called View, and manually adjusting the X and Y coordinates