# Xcode 6.3 Storyboard Scenes Cannot Be Dragged Around

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

**Environment**

OS: OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.3
IDE: Xcode Version 6.3.1

**Precondition(s)**

1. Project created as Single View Application.
2. XCode configuration
   state is in the default state (same as when initially downloaded).

**Problem**
This problem is less about source code in that it pertains in part to the IDE tool.  XCode offers this feature to design UIs and workflows in an interface builder called Storyboards.  Every Storyboard has a scene, and from videos of XCode 5+, it appears you can drag these scenes around to organize them along with the segues.  For my IDE instance, I can drag-n-drop scenes from the Object Library into the editor, but once there, I can no longer adjust or move them around.  The scenes appear "pinned" to the editor.  This results in scenes overlapping one another.  Basically, I have a ball of scenes in the middle of my editor currently.

**Research Background**
I have spent the better part of the day exploring XCode for ways to enable adjustments and/or googling.  Googling this issue has not helped as XCode documentation seems to assume this is intuitive and works out-of-the-box (which is how it should be IMO).  Results for developers having issues with dragging-n-dropping objects/scenes into the editor seems to be more common so any results for this, if any, gets eclipsed.

**Questions**
So I have the following questions:

1. Is there a switch or configuration that I have somehow missed in XCode that essentially "unpins" these scenes from the editor?
2. Or is it a bug/new feature that has either a workaround/new concept to apply/learn?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875543/why-cant-i-move-ios-storyboard-elements-around

Comment: @JakubVano: I have not.  I am using Synergy so I will try this out tomorrow.  Thank you for the lead!